# Word OLE Automation - delete first page and manipulate header and footer

Tags: com, automation, ms-word, ms-office, ole

I am using PHP to start Word Automation and manipulate word documents, but i guess it can be done in all any other language. What i need to do is quite simple, i need to remove the first page and add header and footer.

Here is my code:

```
 $word = new COM('word.applicantion');
 $word->Documents->Open('xxx.docx');
 $word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($result_file_name, 12);
```

Any samples?

Comment: The object model doesn't really have the concept of "page" the way you might think it does. A Word document is a flow document, so by removing the first page, you'll have a new first page with all the previously second page stuff. Secondly, when you say add header/footer, are you just looking for a standard one or are you look for odd/even and first page headers/footers?

Comment: @Otaku, I do want to remove the first page and have a new first page as the second page. And i also want to add a .jpg as a footer to all the pages and some text as the header.

Comment: @aviv: does the below answer your question?

Comment: @Otaku, i will try to implement the code in PHP and see if it works. If it will work i will sign it as the acceptable answer. I will take care of it until the end of this week. Anyhow, this helps me A LOT and thank you very much for submitting it !

Comment: @aviv: Just wanted to check in to see how the PHP implementation is going and if you need any further help.

Comment: @Otaku - thanks a lot, it worked with a few minor changes. I post here my full code. Can you please maybe give some links for some info about word automation / OLE?

Comment: @Otaku - hi - do you know how do i add a watermark using OLE?

Comment: @aviv: open a new question and I'm sure either me or someone else can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you could do it in VBA. This can likely be ported to PHP fairly simply.

```
Sub RemoveFirstPageAndAddHeaderFooter()
    Dim d As Document
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Dim pageOne As Range
    Set pageOne = d.Bookmarks("\page").Range
    pageOne.Select
    Selection.Delete
    d.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Text = "Some text"
    d.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\beigeplum.jpg", False, True
End Sub
```

Note on the `...InlineShapes.AddPicture` - the onus would be on you to ensure the picture is the right size. If you want more control over this, you would use `.Footers(1).Shapes.AddPicture` instead as that let's you set the width/height, top/left, etc.

Answer (score 1):

try
        {
            $word = new COM("word.application") //$word = new COM("C:\x.docx");
                or die("couldnt create an instance of word");

```
        //bring word to the front
        $word->Visible = 1;

        //open a word document
        $word->Documents->Open("file.docx");

        // remove first page
        $range = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("\page");
        $range->Select();
        $word->Selection->Delete();

        //save the document as docx
        $word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("modified_file.docx", 12); // SaveAs('filename', format) // format: 0 - same?, 1 - doc?, 2 - text,  4 - text other encoding
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "error class.document.php - convert_to_docx: $e 20100816.01714";
    }

    //close word
    if($word)
        $word->Quit();

    //free object resources
    //$word->Release();
    $word = null;
```